# Memory leak when using 'node-fetch' and 'jsdom'

Tags: node.js, npm, import, memory-leaks, jsdom

I'm trying to solve a memory leak when running the below code, called runeveryminute.js, once a minute. Every time, I'm seeing a ~5MB increase in data usage that isn't getting garbage collected. When I look at the files using the devtools, it looks like Window is taking up a lot of the space, which makes me think it's an issue with jsdom but I can't figure it out.

[image]

**Example of runeveryminute.js** For the purposes of my example here:

- 'Homepage.html' is a saved copy of Hacker News homepage (https://news.ycombinator.com/)
- 'intermediate.pem' is a file with a bunch of SSL certificates that I am using

**Here is the code:**

```
 import {JSDOM}           from 'jsdom';
    import fetch           from 'node-fetch';
    import UserAgent       from 'user-agents';
    import path from 'path';
    import sslrootcas from 'ssl-root-cas';
    const rootCas = sslrootcas.create();
    import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
    rootCas.addFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'intermediate.pem'));
    import http from 'node:http';
    import https from 'node:https';
    import fs from 'fs';
    
export const emailstripperSO =  function(){
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/config/Homepage.html', 'utf8', function(err, storeBody) {
let dom = new JSDOM(storeBody);
    let atagpromises = [];
    const httpAgent = new http.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
    });
    const httpsAgent =  new https.Agent({ca: rootCas});
      for (var alist of dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("a")){
        let atagpromise = new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
        let oldURL = alist.href;   
        let requestOptions  = {
          host: oldURL.split('/')[2]
          ,path: '/'+oldURL.split('/').slice(3).join('/')
          ,headers: {"User-Agent":  new UserAgent() }    
        }; 
        if (oldURL.split(":")[0] && ["http", "https", "mailto"].includes(oldURL.split(":")[0] ) 
          ){
          if (oldURL.substr(0,4)!="http"){
            return resolve(oldURL);
          }
            if  (oldURL.substr(0,5)=="http:" )  {
              var myAgent = httpAgent;
             }
            if  (oldURL.substr(0,5)=="https" )  {
              var myAgent = httpAgent;
            } 
          // // return fetch(oldURL, {
          fetch(oldURL, {
            method: "GET"
            ,headers: {"User-Agent":  new UserAgent() }
            , redirect: "manual"
            // , agent: myAgent
             ,agent: function(_parsedURL) {
                if (_parsedURL.protocol == 'http:') { return httpAgent;}
                if (_parsedURL.protocol == 'https:') { return httpsAgent;} 
             }
                 })
          .then(response => {
            var newURL = response.url;
            console.log("new linke "+newURL);
            alist.href = newURL ;    
          })
          .catch(err=>{
            console.log("error");
            console.log(err);
            resolve(oldURL);
          });
        }  
        // }
        else {
          console.log("Skipped visiting <"+oldURL+">");
          resolve(oldURL);
        }
      });         
      atagpromises.push(atagpromise);
    };
    Promise.all(atagpromises)
    .then(data=>{
      var serializedDom = dom.serialize();
      //do more stuff with serializedDom here
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log("Error in atagpromises: "+err); 
    });
  });
}
```

**What I have tried:**
I suspected the issue might be with Agent so I tried a couple different ways of coding Agent() as you can see from the commented out portions but both produced memory leaks. Agent needs to switch between http and https because sometimes redirect links redirect between http and https URLs.

Comment: Please show the relevant code that is loading the module every minute.  A minimal, reproducible example has nothing at all to do with what you found in searches.  It's for you to show us enough of your code that we can see/reproduce what is going on.

Comment: I will delete this post soon as I have posted another with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449839/memory-leak-when-using-node-fetch-and-jsdom

Comment: You're not supposed to post another question on the same topic.  You're supposed to FIX you're existing question.  You can use the "Edit" link under your question to edit your content.

Comment: OK. I will delete that post and I am editing this one. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Are you destroying your agents? I see you are using keepalive, so the recommendation is to [destroy](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#agentdestroy) them.

Comment: Good point, no I wasn't destroying them. However, I tried removing the keepalive statement (it wasn't necessary, actually) and the problem persists. It feels something like that, though, like the JSDOM is being kept when it shouldn't be.

Comment: You seem to be creating more agents than you need. The two at the top right after the imports seem unnecessary.

Comment: You're right - those were leftover from when I was making this example. I've removed them from the example code above. The problem persists without them.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say if you have a memory leak or if the garbage collector just decides not to clean up as long as there is enough memory available.

You can restrict the memory usage of Node.js by setting the old_space:

```
node --max_old_space_size=200 app.js
```

The number is the maximum size in megabytes. Finding out a good value requires testing multiple values.

Comment: I tried adding --max_old_space_size=150 and that seemed to run fine for a few times, but eventually I could see it hit 150MB in the console and then the program stopped running. I think it is some kind of memory leak, but I haven't been able to isolate it yet.